# How to read vfat attributes of files in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux

I have a FAT filesystem mounted in Linux with the vfat driver. 
I want to know how I would be able to read the vfat attributes of a file such as "hidden" and "read-only".

Based on what I've read so far, if I use the `stat()` glibc command on a file, I would only be getting the file attributes listed here: 
http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Attribute-Meanings.html#Attribute-Meanings

These don't contain any vfat attributes however. Can anybody help?

Thanks,

Katsupoy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FAT's DOS attributes do not map well to the UNIX filesystem model, so Linux's `vfat` driver does not reflect them.

Instead of mounting the filesystem, use [mtools](http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/intro.html) to read the filesystem from userspace.

---

**Edit** I lied.  Apparently the `vfat` driver is able to deal with these DOS attributes, at least as of 2.4.29 (I think; my historical logs don't go back that far).

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/msdos_fs.h>

int fd = open("/mnt/fat/...", ...);
__u32 attrs;
ioctl(fd, FAT_IOCTL_GET_ATTRIBUTES, &attrs);
attrs = ATTR_NONE;  /* ATTR_{RO,HIDDEN,SYS,VOLUME,DIR,ARCH} */
ioctl(fd, FAT_IOCTL_SET_ATTRIBUTES, &attrs);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely be trying mtools. 
Aside from mtools, is there any other known way (or hack) to be able to retrieve the FAT attributes?

Comment: This is better, I'll be trying this in my machine tomorrow. 

Where is FAT_IOCTL_GET_ATTRIBUTES (and maybe other options that might be useful to me) documented? Thanks.

Comment: I found them while digging through `/usr/src/linux/fs/fat/file.c` -- I've never seen any documentation about these ioctls before.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648117/how-to-get-more-vfat-attributes-of-files-in-linux-using-c