# Reading Windows file attributes from Linux (FAT or NTFS file system)

Tags: c, linux

Is there any quick and dirty way to read the Windows file attributes from a FAT/NTFS partition, from Linux? For example, to check if a file is read only, system, hidden, etc.
And without uncommon libraries (such as linking with Wine).

Comment: check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648117/how-to-get-more-vfat-attributes-of-files-in-linux-using-c)

Comment: Thanks. Following your link I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644416/how-to-read-vfat-attributes-of-files-in-linux-using-c I will try it soon, see if it works.