# Can I get file attributes (hidden/archive...) with boost filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I am using boost::filesystem to copy a directory recursively. I would like to exclude hidden files. Is it possible to get the FAT32 file attributes like "hidden" or "archive" using boost filesystem?

Thanks,

Philipp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost::filesystem currently restricts itself to POSIX file attributes. However, the file_status class documentation indicates that the implementation could be extended at any time.  I would guess this is just waiting on someone motivated to do the work.

Comment: The FAT filesystem drivers on several operating systems that boost::filesystem supports have no interface that'd allow a user process to query FAT-specific attributes. One can do it on Windows for sure, and on Linux via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644416/how-to-read-vfat-attributes-of-files-in-linux-using-c but if you need support on other operating systems, there'll be way more work ...